# PHP, XML - Get child nodes and their attributes

Tags: php, xml, dom, codeigniter

How do i get all the "seat" child nodes and their attributes from this XML file?

```
   <seatmap id="1">
      <seat row="A" seatnum="01" available="1" />
      <seat row="A" seatnum="02" available="1" />
      <seat row="A" seatnum="03" available="1" />
      <seat row="A" seatnum="04" available="1" />
      <seat row="A" seatnum="05" available="1" />
    </seatmap>
```

I have different seatmaps, so i want to get them by querying with an ID
then assigning all the 'seat' nodes and their attributes to variables.

I've been using DOM methods so far, but maybe simpleXML or XPath would be easier as its really
confusing as you drill down from DOMDocumet, DOMElement, DOMNode.

Any help would be great, cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$XML = <<<XML
<parent>
   <seatmap id="1">
      <seat row="A" seatnum="01" available="1" />
      <seat row="A" seatnum="02" available="1" />
      <seat row="A" seatnum="03" available="1" />
      <seat row="A" seatnum="04" available="1" />
      <seat row="A" seatnum="05" available="1" />
    </seatmap>
</parent>
XML;

$xml_nodes = new SimpleXMLElement($XML);

$nodes = $xml_nodes->xpath('//seatmap[@id = "1"]/seat'); // Replace the ID value with whatever seatmap id you're trying to access

foreach($nodes as $seat)
{
    // You can then access: $seat['row'], $seat['seatnum'], $seat['available']
}
```

Comment: Will only work is `seatmap` is a first level node, but +1 anyway :)

Comment: @Tim Cooper how can you pass a xml file to the simplexmlelement class?

Comment: @RIKL:  `$xml_nodes = new SimpleXMLElement($filename, 0, true);`.

Answer (score 1):

Easily can be done with DOM:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('xmlfile.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$seats = $xpath->query('//seatmap[@id="1"]/seat');
if ($seats->length) {
    foreach ($seats as $seat) {
        echo "row: ".$seat->getAttribute('row').PHP_EOL;
        echo "seatnum: ".$seat->getAttribute('seatnum').PHP_EOL;
        echo "available: ".$seat->getAttribute('available').PHP_EOL;
    }
} else {
    die('seatmap not found or is empty');
}
```